# my page won't properly center and resize with the broswer window

Tags: html, css

I'm building a basic HTML site that has 4 pages.  3 of the 4 pages will properly resize itself as the browser window grows/shrinks.  1 page contains a bunch of pictures and for some reason the items on the page all shift over to the left side of the page and won't center properly on the page or properly shrink to fit the width of the broswer.  i don't know what else to do.  i've tried using various margin and width commands and nothing seems to work.  below is a a portion of my page:

----- BELOW IS THE HTML I USED -----

```
<body id="top">


<!-- MAIN IMAGE -->


<div id="auto">
<center><img src="images/car.JPG" alt="car" name="image" width="248" height="145" id="image" /></center>
</div>


<!-- SITE NAME -->


<div id="header">
<p style="position:relative; top: -20px">####</p>
</div>


<!-- MAIN LINKS -->


<div>
<ul id="buttons" style="position:relative; top: -50px">
    <li><a href="index.html" style="color:#E5E5E5">home</a></li>
    <li><a href="gallery.html" style="color:#E5E5E5">gallery</a></li>
    <li><a href="search.html" style="color:#E5E5E5">search</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact.html" style="color:#E5E5E5">contact</a></li>
</ul>
</div>


<!-- MFR TABLE -->


<div id="links">
    <table height="45%" align="center" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="5" id="mfr" style="position: relative; top: -50px;">
        <tr>
            <td class="links"><img  width="116" height="106" /></td>
            <td class="links"><img  width="177" height="82" /></td>
            <td class="links"><img  width="148" height="118" /></td>
            <td class="links"><img  width="190" height="111" /></td>
            <td class="links"><img  width="102" height="115" /></td>
            <td class="links"><img  width="136" height="136" /></td>   
        </tr>
</div>
</body>
```

----- BELOW IS THE CSS I USED ----

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* gallery */

body {background-color: white;
        border-color: #4E4E4E;
        padding: 50px;  
}

div p {font-size:60px;
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        color: #7F7F7F;
        text-align:center;
}

#buttons {font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
            font-size: 25px;
            margin: 50px auto;
            padding: 20px;
            text-align: center;
}

div li {display: inline;
        background-color:#616161;
        padding: 5px;
}

#image {text-align: center;
}

#links {margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    width: 70%;
    height: 50%;
}

a {text-decoration: none;
color:#FFF;
}

p {text-align:center;
    font-size: 20px;
}

#mfr {height: 50%;
        text-align: center;
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.links {background-color: white;
    color: black;
    font-size: 18px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.visit {background-color:#771C2E;
    color: #FFF;
    font-size: 18px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    width:330px;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "center properly" or "shrink to fit the browser" (try to be as specific as possible). However, here is a very basic jsfiddle which shows how to manipulate images in certain ways which may match what you are looking for. http://jsfiddle.net/15r2qdph/1/

Answer (score 0):

there are some of my suggestions for you. I little rewrite you source code, so you can easier see some of mistakes. Please look in it, maybe it could be for you helpful.

Maybe you can take case of:
* writing styles only on one place, preferably only in CSS file - this can prevent duplicities, and you can easier orient in you code
* prevent relative positioning if not needed, you can create space between blocks easily with margins and paddings
* prevent setting percentage height of block if not needed

My / your source:, you can try it and maybe let me know :)

HTML:

```
<body id="top">

    <!-- MAIN IMAGE -->
    <div id="auto">
        <center><img src="images/car.JPG" alt="car" name="image" width="248" height="145" id="image" /></center>
    </div>

    <!-- SITE NAME -->
    <div id="header">
        <p>####</p>
    </div>


    <!-- MAIN LINKS -->
    <div>
        <ul id="buttons">
            <li><a href="index.html">home</a></li>
            <li><a href="gallery.html">gallery</a></li>
            <li><a href="search.html">search</a></li>
            <li><a href="contact.html">contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>


    <!-- MFR TABLE -->
    <div id="links">
        <table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="5" id="mfr">
            <tr>
                <td class="links"><img  width="116" height="106" /></td>
                <td class="links"><img  width="177" height="82" /></td>
                <td class="links"><img  width="148" height="118" /></td>
                <td class="links"><img  width="190" height="111" /></td>
                <td class="links"><img  width="102" height="115" /></td>
                <td class="links"><img  width="136" height="136" /></td>   
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>

</body>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    background-color: white;
    border-color: #4E4E4E;
    padding: 50px;  
    font-size: 20px;
}

img {
    border: 1px solid gray;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color:#FFF;
}

#auto {
    text-align: center;
}

#header p {
    font-size:60px;
    color: #7F7F7F;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 20px 0;
}

#buttons {
    font-size: 25px;
    margin: 20px 0;
    text-align: center;
    list-style: none;
}

#buttons li {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color:#616161;
    padding: 5px;
}

#buttons li a {
    color:#E5E5E5;
}

#mfr {
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.links {
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
    font-size: 18px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.visit {
    background-color:#771C2E;
    color: #FFF;
    font-size: 18px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    width:330px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you kamienok, I will try executing your suggestion/corrections.